# How to copy folders from .jar file into local drive

Tags: java, cygwin

I want to Run shell script using Cygwin in java.i want to add these scripts as a part of executable.
But these scripts should in c:\cygwin\bin\ folder. So how to include scripts as a part of my executable and how to paste them into c:\cygwin\bin\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***You can do the same in java program***

**Step-1** create a zip file of a folder containing all the necessary script files (which will be put in external directory).

**Step-2** attach this zip file to java project.

**Step-3** When application launches (eg inside launcher Main method) write the logic to check whether those files available in the specified directory. If those file doesn't exists then create the directory structure and extract the zipped scripting file there. This things you can do in java programming

**Step-4** Create jar of the whole project.